# Django: openpyxl saving workbook as attachment

Tags: python, django, excel, xlsx, openpyxl

Hi I have a quick question. I didn't find answer in internet maybe someone of you can help me.

So i want to save workbook as attachment but I don't know how lets see an example :

```
    from openpyxl import Workbook
    from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
    wb = Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    dest_filename = 'file.xlsx'
    ws = wb.worksheets[0]
    ws.title = "range names"
    for col_idx in xrange(1, 40):
        col = get_column_letter(col_idx)
        for row in xrange(1, 600):
            ws.cell('%s%s'%(col, row)).value = '%s%s' % (col, row)
    ws = wb.create_sheet()
    ws.title = 'Pi'
    ws.cell('F5').value = 3.14
```

Then I tried :

```
response = HttpResponse(wb, content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="foo.xls"'
return response
```

It's returning xlsx file indeed but in file there is only object adres not the content of file:

```
<openpyxl.workbook.Workbook object at 0x00000000042806D8>
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: Have you tried to instantiate `output = StringIO.StringIO()`, then write to it via `openpyxl.writer.excel.save_workbook` method and pass `output.getvalue()` to `HttpResponse` constructor? Let me know if it helps - I'll add it as an answer.

Comment: One more option is to use `openpyxl.writer.excel.save_virtual_workbook` method.

Comment: `response = HttpResponse(save_virtual_workbook(wb), content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')`
Working Thanks mate :)) make this comment as answer I will mark it as corrected

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Give it a try:

```
from openpyxl.writer.excel import save_virtual_workbook
...
response = HttpResponse(save_virtual_workbook(wb), content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
```

`save_virtual_workbook` was specially designed for your use case. Here's a docstring:

> """Return an in-memory workbook, suitable for a Django response."""

Comment: Thx! That wasn't immediately obvious in the documentation as it's only mentioned in the generated docs

Comment: It's working , But when I downloaded it on Front End side(Created of Angular Js)  , It's giving me some unicode things (Dirty data). Do I need to add something in Angular code?

Comment: Hi! This has been deprecated from openpyxl by this commit: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/commits/2c8045bc3abf6a637f9f93400d8e0f603506a133. Looking for snippets to use NamedTemporaryFile instead :)

Answer (score 5):

On at least some versions of django/python/openpyxl, the given solution does not work. See https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/657/save_virtual_workbook-generates-junk-data

Simple working solution:

```
wb = Workbook(write_only=True, encoding='utf-8')
ws = wb.create_sheet()
for row in data:
    ws.append([str(cell) for cell in row])
response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.ms-excel')
wb.save(response)
```

What's happening here is that Django's HttpResponse is a file-like object. `Workbook.save()` can take a file-like object. (Internally, it uses [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html), which takes either a filename or a file-like object.)

If you're manipulating the file in memory, this is the simplest and probably most efficient solution. A streaming response doesn't really make sense since the data is not being created with a generator. Even if save_virtual_workbook works, the data it writes is generated as a block before it's readable.

The other option would be to create a NamedTemporaryFile (from [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html) or Django's wrapper), pass that into `Workbook.save()`, then use [FileResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#fileresponse-objects) to stream that from the filesystem instead of from memory.

Answer (score 4):

I usually use

```
ws = wb.add_sheet("Pi")
```

instead of

```
ws = wb.create_sheet()
ws.title = "Pi"
```

Moreover, you can try to do: (see [documentation](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/doc/xlwt.html?p=4966))

```
wb.save(stream)
```

and then use stream in HttpResponse.

Comment: What is the type of this stream value ?

Comment: You can use StringIO, e.g.

Comment: in Python 3 it must be `ByteIO` instead of `StringIO`

Answer (score 0):

You can try also the following code lines.
You can also set your file name as you want.

```
wb = Workbook()
..............
..............
response = HttpResponse(save_virtual_workbook(wb),content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='+str(yourFileName)+'_report'+'.xlsx'
return response
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).